# How do I grab the value of my chosen item in a drop down menu?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to push the value of the chosen drop down item into an array but the jQuery command I am using will only push a value of 1, no matter which drop down item is selected.

The command I have been trying to use is:

```
newFriend.response.push($("#ddi1").val())
```

or

```
newFriend.response.push($("#dropdown-q1").val())
```

My code is:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdowns" id="chosen-q1">Make a Selection</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-q1">
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="1" selected="selected">1 (Strongly Disagree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="2" selected="selected">2 (Disagree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="3" selected="selected">3 (Neutral)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="4" selected="selected">4 (Agree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="5" selected="selected">5 (Strongly Agree)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various errors in your code. First, you have all of the list items selected, also  each one has the same id (ids are only meant to be used once). You also have two ids on your button. 
I would recommend you use a  option group for this task like so:

```js
$("#dropdown-q1").change(function() {
  var $x = $('#dropdown-q1 :selected').val();
  console.log ($x)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="chosen-q1">Make a Selection</button>
    <br><br>
    <select class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-q1">
      <option class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="1" selected="selected">1 (Strongly Disagree)</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" id="ddi2" value="2">2 (Disagree)</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" id="ddi2" value="3" >3 (Neutral)</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" id="ddi4" value="4" >4 (Agree)</option>
      <option class="dropdown-item" id="ddi5" value="5" >5 (Strongly Agree)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use an alert but console.log is neater..

Hope this helps

Comment: Would I have to change my ul and li tags to select and option for this to work? Or can I leave as is?

Comment: Change to select and option, it's not a big job. You haven't offered a way of selecting an option as your code stands. If you want to display all 5 options , you need to at least have a radio group ...

Comment: I made the change to select and option but it completely messes up my button to the point where a selection is not possible for the user. Would you recommend switching to radio buttons?

Comment: I haven't seen the rest of your code, and it shouldn't mess up the button. 8 would recommend further investigating your own code.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is for `input`, `select`, and `textarea` types, and its behavior will be undefined for `<ul>`s, as far as I know.

You can find which of your `<li>` is selected by altering your current selector to include the list item that has the attribute value "selected" set to "selected":

```
$('#dropdown-q1 li[selected="selected"]').attr('value');
```

I think your markup might not represent your actual code though; *all* items in your example have the "selected" attribute the same. I assume you just want one.

Once you have **one** selected value (the above will return the *first* one it finds), you can push the value:

```
var selectedValue = $('#dropdown-q1 li[selected="selected"]').attr('value');
newFriend.response.push(selectedValue);
```

Here's some code in action (watch the console output):

```js
console.log($('#dropdown-q1 li[selected="selected"]').attr('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdowns" id="chosen-q1">Make a Selection</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-q1">
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="1" selected="">1 (Strongly Disagree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="2" selected="">2 (Disagree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="3" selected="">3 (Neutral)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="4" selected="selected">4 (Agree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="5" selected="">5 (Strongly Agree)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I see what you mean with all of the <li> being "selected". I'm confused how to set that specific <li> as the selected item such that it pushes the value when the user makes their choice in the application.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is trigger `.click()` event ( or `.change()`if you are using `input`/`select` tags).

The below example will trigger click event and push the value of clicked `<li>` to `newFriend.response`

Edit:

```js
//define your variable globally outside 
var newFriend = {};
 newFriend.response = [];

//push to array on select
$("#dropdown-q1 li").on("click", function(){
//console.log("value: "+this.value);
newFriend.response.push(this.value);
});




$("#submit-button").on("click", function (event) {  event.preventDefault(); 
 newFriend.name = $("#name").val().trim();
 newFriend.photoLink = $("#photo").val().trim();
 console.log(newFriend); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdowns" id="chosen-q1">Make a Selection</button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-q1">
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="1" selected="selected">1 (Strongly Disagree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="2" selected="selected">2 (Disagree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="3" selected="selected">3 (Neutral)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="4" selected="selected">4 (Agree)</li>
                <li class="dropdown-item" id="ddi1" value="5" selected="selected">5 (Strongly Agree)</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<input id="name" value="Mohamed"/>
<input id="photo" value="http://photoLink/"/>
<button id="submit-button">submit</button>
```

Comment: I have an on click function for the submit button on the bottom of my page. Is there a way to incorporate your code into that?

Comment: `$("#submit-button").on("click", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var newFriend = {
                name: $("#name").val().trim(),
                photoLink: $("#photo").val().trim(),
                response: []
            };

            newFriend.response.push($('#dropdown-q1 li[selected="selected"]').attr('value'));
            

            console.log(newFriend)
});`

Comment: Check now, noting that's just imagination you didn't add full code.

Comment: The only thing is I don't want the value to push until the submit button is clicked because I want the user to be able to edit their response prior to submission if they'd like. Basically I want all the data (from all 10 questions) to be pushed with one click

Comment: You want to push many values to `newFriend.response` or just one value to be submitted with the other data

Comment: Many values. I have 10 questions total, all with their own lists for selection. So I want to push each to the response array.